# is "about English second language teaching and learning" grammatical?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

I came across the following sentence fragment:

> [1] about English second language teaching and learning

I found this sentence fragment hard to understand, so I'd like to rephrase it to be clearer.  Here are my two attempts to do that:

> [2] about teaching and learning English as second language

> [3] about second language English teaching and learning

I have two questions.

1. Is the original sentence fragment actually grammatical?  It's a little difficult for me to parse, which makes me think it might be wrong in the first place.
2. Are either or both of my rephrasings of the sentence fragment correct?  That is, do they still convey the same (intended) meaning of the original, and are they, in themselves, grammatically correct?

Comment: Ignoring the fact that the "head" noun in these examples is the plural element ***teaching and learning***, it would still be hopelessly "jargonny" to string together that long sequence of "attributive adjectives" (some of which are actually ***nouns*** being used adjectivally) before the head noun in ***second language English teaching***. You should prefer something more like ***the teaching of English as a second language*** (where you can directly replace ***teaching*** by ***teaching and learning*** if required).

Comment: ...#1 is non-idiomatic because of the specific *sequence* of the adjectival usages, and #2 is syntactically invalid because it lacks the indefinite article in *as **a** second language*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see, but would you say all three would deliver the same message without difficulty for the listener to understand, regardless of being grammatical?

Comment: It's obvious what they're *intended* to convey, but I'd say that all three versions tell *me* the same *additional* thing, which is that they all came from a non-native speaker. But if the article is included as per my previous comment, I obviously wouldn't think that about #2.

Comment: A sentence can be technically 'grammatical', without being the clearest or most natural way of expressing the intended meaning.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, a writer would just say that  :)

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer, I hope, and possibly stave off the "close" votes.  It could still be improved further if Euler Henry could state precisely what he thinks might be wrong with the original sentence, and explain his thinking about why he chose these two ways to rephrase it.  A link to the exact place you found this sentence fragment could also help us see the context better.

Comment: @Richard Winters, fair points. what puzzle me the most in thi setence is: "English second language" part I belive it should be: " second language English" this way I am qualifying English as second language.  Maybe i could qualify the "second language" as English but I'm not sure if that is semantical. In general feels more natural to qualify just a noun than a phrase. is that so?

Comment: Also feels weird the "teaching and learning" displayed after "English second language" like: "English second language teaching and learning." What is going on there? is:"English second language" qualifying "teaching and learning"? is that what it is?

Comment: @ Richard Winters, the link is: "https://books4english.quora.com/?__nsrc__=4&__snid3__=29848789270"